# Memsql crashing when running out of memory

Tags: docker, singlestore

We are using memsql for real time analytics purpose. We have created Kafka Connector which is continuously consuming from Kafka and pushing to memsql. After sometime memsql is crashing due to memory issues.

Is there any way to monitor how much memory memsql consumes and how it autoscales.

Answer (score 0):

(by your 'docker' tag, I am guessing that you run 'memsql' in a container)

Assuming that you have access to the host where your 'memsql' container is running and you know the container you want to monitor, the memory usage information is available from the kernel's `cgroups` stats on the host.

You could run the following on the Docker host system:

```
container="your_container_name_or_ID"
set -- `docker inspect $container --format "{{.Id}} {{.HostConfig.CgroupParent}}"`
id="$1"
cg="$2"
if [ -z "$cg" ] ; then
cg=/docker
fi

cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory${cg}/${id}/memory.max_usage_in_bytes
```

This will print the peak memory usage of all processes running in the container's cgroup (that is, the initial process started by the container's ENTRYPOINT and any child processes that it might have ran).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check how much memory your memsql nodes are using run:

```
select * from information_schema.mv_nodes
```

There is a more details about how memsql uses memory here:

https://help.memsql.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001091386-What-Is-Using-Memory-on-My-Leaves-